# table() function in r - is there a better way with e.g., dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I am trying to create a basic table with frequencies of a categorical variable (Relationship_type) grouped by another variable (Country), preferably using dplyr library (or anything else that is easier to export as a .csv file than table()).

```
head(d)
Country                        Relationship_type
1 Algeria                                      2
2 Bulgaria                                     1
3 USA                                          2
4 Algeria                                      3
5 Germany                                      2
6 USA                                          1
```

I want this to look like an output from basic table(d$Country, d$Relationship_type) function:

```
                    2   3   4
  Algeria         141  47 137
  Australia       128  27 103
  Austria          97   5  17
  Belgium         172  16  71
  Brazil          104   6  70
  CHILE            54   4  46
```

Tried several combinations of tally(), group_by, count() etc. but can't figure it out.

Could you please help a bit??

All the best,
R_beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to use `tables::tabular()` as follows.

```
textData <- "id Country                        Relationship_type
1 Algeria                                      2
2 Bulgaria                                     1
3 USA                                          2
4 Algeria                                      3
5 Germany                                      2
6 USA                                          1
7 Algeria                                      1
8 Bulgaria                                     3
9 USA                                          2
10 Algeria                                     2
11 Germany                                     1
12 USA                                         3"

df <- read.table(text=textData,header=TRUE)
library(tables)
tabular(Factor(Country) ~ Factor(Relationship_type),data=df)
```

...and the output:

```
          Relationship_type    
 Country  1                 2 3
 Algeria  1                 2 1
 Bulgaria 1                 0 1
 Germany  1                 1 0
 USA      1                 2 1
```

Still another approach is to recast the output from `table()` as a data frame, and pivot it wider with `tidyr::pivot_wider()`.

```
# another approach: recast table output as data.frame
tableData <- data.frame(table(df$Country,df$Relationship_type))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tableData %>% 
     pivot_wider(id_cols = Var1,
                 names_from = Var2,
                 values_from = Freq)
```

...and the output:

```
> tableData %>% 
+      pivot_wider(id_cols = Var1,
+                  names_from = Var2,
+                  values_from = Freq)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Var1       `1`   `2`   `3`
  <fct>    <int> <int> <int>
1 Algeria      1     2     1
2 Bulgaria     1     0     1
3 Germany      1     1     0
4 USA          1     2     1
```

If we add a `dplyr::rename()` to the pipeline, we can rename the `Var1` column to `Country`.

```
tableData %>% 
     pivot_wider(id_cols = Var1,
                 names_from = Var2,
                 values_from = Freq) %>%
     rename(Country = Var1)
```

As usual, there are many ways in R to accomplish this task. Depending on the reason why the desired output is a CSV file, there are a variety of approaches that could fit the requirements. If the ultimate goal is to create presentation quality tables, then it's worth a look at this summary of packages that create presentation quality tables: [How gt fits with other packages that create display tables](https://gt.rstudio.com/#how-gt-fits-in-with-other-packages-that-generate-display-tables).

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! I will definitely check the gt:) The tabular gave me only one's in each of the Relationship_type column, as I have numerous participants from the given Country as was shown with the table() output I added in the first post (and not the binary yes or no situation), so I don't think it improves the current situation anyhow.

ooo! Haven't noticed your pivot suggestion. That's what I have been looking for, THANK YOU!

Comment: @chillos - thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer. If you remove the *(N=1) `tabular()` will automatically count the number of observations. I also added test data to demonstrate that the updated solution works, as you can see from the output where both solutions now have a total of 12 counts across the table cells, and some of the counts are >1.

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed use `count`:

```
d %>% count(Country, Relationship_type)
```

It's not really better than `table` but it saves the `$` use at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, it is not equivalent to the output of table() :( But I think I managed to go around that by a long and rubbish lines as follow:

~test <- d %>% count(Country, Relationship_type)
test$Country <- as.factor(test$Country)
test <- test[complete.cases(test$Relationship_type),]
test_wide <- spread(test, Relationship_type, n)~